# Find-and-replace only when the pattern is following by something

Tags: json, sed, replace, ag

I have a lot of Jupyter notebooks that contain the following pattern

```py
try:
    import tensorflow as tf
except:
    %pip install tensorflow
    import tensorflow as tf
```

According to [pylint](https://vald-phoenix.github.io/pylint-errors/plerr/errors/exceptions/W0703.html), I should provide a more specific exception object, i.e.

```py
try:
    import tensorflow as tf
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    %pip install tensorflow
    import tensorflow as tf
```

That's the basic idea, but to be more precise, the notebooks are essentially JSON files, and they actually contain something like

```json
"try:\n",
"    import tensorflow\n",
"except:\n",
"    %pip install tensorflow\n",
"    import tensorflow\n",
```

Since there are hundreds of notebooks, I cannot go over them manually, so I planned to do a find-and-replace with `ag` and `sed`, e.g.

```
ag -l '^"except:\\\\n",$' | xargs sed -i '' 's/except:/except ModuleNotFoundError:/g'
```

However, not all `except:` blocks contain `%pip install` statements. How can I replace all `except:` with `except ModuleNotFoundError:` only if it's followed by a `%pip install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/except:/{N;/%pip install/{s/except:/except ModuleNotFoundError:/}}' input_file
try:
    import tensorflow as tf
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    %pip install tensorflow
    import tensorflow as tf
```

- Match lines with `except:`
- If the `N;` next line contains the string `%pip install` then
- Match only the `except:` with `%pip install` as the next line and change it to `except ModuleNotFoundError:`

Comment: Could you explain the command a little bit, e.g. why `except:` appears twice, so that I can adapt it to the JSON file?

Comment: @nalzok Please check edit

Comment: I got `sed: 1: "/except:/{N;/%pip insta ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`. Presumably because I am on macOS, which bundles with BSD `sed`? **EDIT:** it works after I installed `gsed`!

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `sed` might be:

```
sed '/except:/{N;/:\n[[:space:]]*%pip install/{s// ModuleNotFoundError&0/}}' file
```

- When matching `except:`
- Read (append) the next line to the pattern space using `N`
- If the current pattern space matches `:\n[[:space:]]*%pip install`
- Use the last matched pattern `//` and replace with `ModuleNotFoundError` followed by the full match `&0`

This pattern `:\n[[:space:]]*%pip install` matches the `:` a newline and optional spaces and then `%pip install`

Output

```
try:
    import tensorflow as tf
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    %pip install0 tensorflow
    import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: I got `sed: 1: "/except:/{N;/:\n[[:spac ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`. Presumably because I am on macOS, which bundles with BSD `sed`? **EDIT:** it works after I installed `gsed`!